# Child elements break out of parent, even though parent has no height set?

Tags: html, css

This is probably pretty hard to explain, so for good measure, I've placed a mock-up on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HZpBG/

I have `#box-cont` with no set height, which usually (at least from my experience anyway), means that it takes the sum heights of all of it's nested elements + any padding.

However, `.valid` and `.invalid` (which as far as I can tell are contained within `#box-cont`)seem to be running off the bottom, not only of `#box-cont` but of `.box-bottom` too.

On to the question, can anyone point out why this is happening?

I've gone back and forth in attempt to diagnose what the problem is to no avail :(.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;)!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the `height` is not set explicitly on the div with an `id` of `box-cont`, you can simply set: `overflow: hidden;` [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HZpBG/4/).

Comment: Works perfectly, with no breaks in the background color. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `clear: both;` to `box-bottom` class:

```
.box-bottom {
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000 no-repeat;
    clear: both;
}
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HZpBG/1/

Floating elements are indeed "outside" the ordinary flow of elements.

Comment: Props for that :). Time to read up on the `clear:` property for me, I'll accept your answer when the timer drops :).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that it creates a break. I've got a different colored background for `body` to that of `#box-cont`, which creates http://jsfiddle.net/HZpBG/3/. Any chances of getting around that?

Comment: @Pixelatron - create a new element that uses `clear` within `box-cont`, not outside on `.box-bottom`. See [this JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HZpBG/7/)

Comment: You can also get rid of the clears completely and just add `overflow:hidden` to `#box-cont`

Comment: Cheers, looks like the overflow way is better indeed. :)